exe file not found by using powershell script
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$XML = @"
    <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Title="windows update" Height="480" Width="640">
         <Grid Background="#FFC1C3CB">

        <Button Name="WU" Content="lancer la MAJ" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="54"/>

        <TextBox Name="PCWU" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="145,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="D23-0494" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"/>
        <Button Name="Close" Content="Fermer la fenêtre" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="54"/>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
"@

$FormXML = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XML)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($FormXML)

$Window.FindName("WU").add_click({

$computer = $Window.FindName('PCWU').Text
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {.\Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe /QuietInstall /SkipEULA /NoRestartUI}
})
$Window.FindName("Close").add_click({

$Window.Close()

})
$Window.ShowDialog()

i have this code to install windows11 with the assistant but when I click to update the shell say objectnotFound
I tried to move the file to the root of the PC but it doesn't work either

Why don't you simply specify the full path and filename for Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe ?

When you start a PowerShell remote session, it starts in the ~\Documents directory of the remote target computer. You can CD to the parent directory of Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe executable before running it. Be aware that the parent directory is not limited to be local to the remote, it can be a network share residing on the computer opening the PSSession.
...
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location 'path\to\parent\directory\at\the\remote\computer'
  .\Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe /QuietInstall /SkipEULA /NoRestartUI
}
...

If you would like to keep the working directory to the default one, add the Parent directory to the PATH environment variable.
...
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
  $Env:Path = "path\to\parent\directory\at\the\remote\computer;$Env:Path"
  Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe /QuietInstall /SkipEULA /NoRestartUI
}
...

Or just use the full path of the executable.
...
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
 
 path\to\parent\directory\at\the\remote\computer\Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe /QuietInstall /SkipEULA /NoRestartUI
}
...

If the path has spaces, you can use the Call operator &
...
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
 
 & 'path\to\parent\directory\at\the\remote\computer\Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe' /QuietInstall /SkipEULA /NoRestartUI
}
...


thank you I thought that the scriptblock took the files from the local PC and not from the remote PC

when you experience a problem where an exe file is not found, you can change the writing format by adding & at begin:
... -ScriptBlock {& .\Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe ...
or saves the path of exe file to a variable:
$WIA = "Full path of Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe"
Then ... -ScriptBlock {$WIA ...
